# Laravel: Confirm a task/notice by multiple users

Tags: laravel

For a simple task/notice board i want that every user leaves a reading confirmation. Every user can write a notice, the other ones have to confirm this.

Each notice will get a single entry in the database, like so:

- id
- date
- garage_id
- description
- confirm
- created_at
- updated_at

In the view I wanted to show the user that have already given a confirmation.

The idea was to store any user id separated by comma in the confirm-field.
but how can I establish a relationship between user and user id by using eloquent and later in the view?

Or does anyone have any other ideas for confirmation?

Thanks
Jack

Comment: Have an intermediate/pivot table. **Do not store a comma separated list and hope to parse it**. That's bad database design and breaks down with large numbers of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a pivot table between your notice table and your user table.

That table allows you to define a many-to-many relationship in your Notice model:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

This way you can get all users that confirm the notice simply by using your relation:

```
Notice::find(notice_id)->users;
```

And when a user confirms:

```
$notice = Notice::find(notice_id)
$notice->users()->attach(user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, now i have the users belongs to every notice, but how can i grab a single user and their id, name etc...? In the view i want to disable the has read button for users, they have already read the notice.

Comment: You can probably use the contains function. $notice->users->contains(user_id) should return true or false if the user has been attached to the notice or not.